# Are ADMIN$ and/or IPC$ shares enabled on Windows 10 machines in environments usually?

Tags: penetration-testing

I am setting up a vulnerable windows 10 machine for use in my home testing lab and wonder if there is a business case for companies to usually have the ADMIN$ and/or IPC$ shares open (writable?) in a Windows active directory environment?

Realism is the goal and I would like to hear comments from anyone who knows.

Without these being open then none of the impacket scripts work. For example wmiexec.py or smbexec.py or psexec.py all rely on these shares being open so if they have to be arbitrarily opened then that's not realistic.

Comment: More often than not, it's the default settings of everything that are in effect. So make a clean install and look if these are active, and if so, with what permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default, those admin shares are enabled on a fresh Windows installation. However, you will need local administrator or domain administrator permissions to access the workstation remotely.

If you have domain admin or local admin permissions but still cannot connect to the admin share, then most likely you need to disable the "UAC Remote Restrictions" feature. See [this article](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/08/access-denied-trying-to-connect-to-administrative-shares-on-windows-7/) for more information.

Potential Error even with local or domain admin rights:

```
\\192.168.175.129\c$ is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
```

In order to disable the UAC Remote Restrictions feature, the following registry key must be created. Windows 8 and Window 10 machines will automatically make the change, Windows Vista and 7 will need a reboot to fully disable the UAC remote restrictions feature.

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Value: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
Data: 1 (to disable, 0 enables filtering)
Type: REG_DWORD (32-bit)
```